# Package deployment in Visual Studio gets stuck

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, powershell, uwp

Working on my first .NET WinForms migration to UWP with a [Windows Application Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) and been playing with deployment & clean-up a couple of days, then suddenly the most recent deployment gets stuck.

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: XXXXXXUwp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
Starting local deployment...
Deploy: START
DeployAsync: START
Reading package recipe file "J:\projects\XXXXXX\XXXXXX-ui\xxx\installer\XXXUpdater\XXXXXXUwp\bin\x64\Debug\XXXXXXUwp.build.appxrecipe"...
Shutting down application: "XXXXXX_1.0.5.0_x64__8pg3jxqw35kvc"
Deployment layout folder location: "J:\projects\XXXXXX\XXXXXX-ui\xxx\installer\XXXUpdater\XXXXXXUwp\bin\x64\Debug\AppX"
Unregistering application "XXXXXX_1.0.5.0_x64__8pg3jxqw35kvc" currently installed at "J:\projects\XXXXXX\XXXXXX-ui\xxx\installer\XXXUpdater\XXXXXXUwp\bin\x64\Release\AppX" not by Visual Studio deployment.
Unregistering application: "XXXXXX_1.0.5.0_x64__8pg3jxqw35kvc"
```

It took so long that I had to cancel, then it logged the ff.

```
DEP4000: Deployment was canceled. 
Deploy: DeploymentSucceeded = False
Deploy: DeploymentError = Err_Deploy_Canceled
Deploy: DeploymentHRESULT = 2147500036
Deploy: HasSharedCode = False
Deploy: Target.Id = 512
Deploy: ProjectGuid = {****}
Deploy: Project.TargetPlatformVersion = 10.0.17763.0
Deploy: Project.TargetPlatformMinVersion = 10.0.17134.0
Deleting file "vs.appxrecipe" from layout...
DeployAsync: END (Failure, 0:02:51.321)
Deploy: END (Failure, 0:02:51.336)
1>Deployment of the application to the target device failed
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Not really sure what caused this to get stuck but I suspect that it is because of the absence of the installation location "J:\projects\XXXXXX\XXXXXX-ui\xxx\installer\XXXUpdater\XXXXXXUwp\bin\x64\Release\AppX" w/c it seems I've cleaned up manually.

This happens even if Visual Studio is already running as admin.

I also tried removing the package via Powershell (running as admin) and it, too, gets stuck - I left it running overnight wishing that it was just taking a long time, but disappointed to come back the next day in the afternoon that it still hasn't progressed.
[image]

I also tried making a new .appx and then run it to update the currently-installed one, but it, too, gets stuck updating at 10%
[image]

UPDATE: I changed the package name and then tried to deploy but it got stuck at this:

```
Copying file "J:\projects\xxxxxx\XXXXXX-ui\xxx\installer\XXXUpdater\XXXXXXUwp\bin\x64\Debug\AppxManifest.xml" to layout "AppxManifest.xml"...
Registering the application to run from layout...
```

Comment: When you deploy it in another machine, will the same issue occur? In addition, you can go to the vs installer and select repair to check your vs.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT, I don't think it will occur in another machine because the problem only occurs in my machine, where it gets stuck in removing the old package.

I also don't think that repairing VS will fix the issue because even in Powershell, it gets stuck removing the package. I also tried another version of VS and it, too, had the same issue.

Comment: First, you can try to update the version number to see if it is blocked by the cache.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT if you mean that I should generate a new .appx w/ incremented version number, then I've already done this; else please let me know what you mean exactly. Thanks! Btw, where is this "cache" and how to reset it? I'm thinking of just re-installing my Win10, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @sjlewis Could you please try to use this PowerShell command: Get-AppxPackage -allusers PackageFullName | Remove-AppxPackage to uninstall the app from all user accounts. It'll take a few moments in uninstalling the app and if you see any error after completion of the command, you may need to restart the computer.

Comment: @AmyPeng-MSFT, this worked! Thank you! It seems I just needed to specify `-allusers`

Comment: That's great! I will repost my comment into the answer part to make sure it will better benefit other community members as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the package is still there after you try to uninstall it, we think it is due to that package data didn't clear completely. Please try to use this PowerShell command: Get-AppxPackage -allusers PackageFullName | Remove-AppxPackage to uninstall the app from all user accounts.

It'll take a few moments in uninstalling the app when using the above command and if you see any error after completion of the command, you may need to restart the computer.

Thanks.